# Recommendations on an MVVM framework for ArcGIS Desktop add-ins and/or ArcGIS WPF Runtime

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in, wpf, arcgis-runtime, model-view-viewmodel

Is anyone using an [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) framework with [ArcGIS Desktop add-ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000) or the [ArcGIS Runtime for WPF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-wpf/)?

I am leaning towards [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) simply because it seems to be the most popular "lightweight" MVVM framework, but I was wondering if anyone had any experience with it or others (or if they are using none at all) before diving in.

My main requirements would be that it work with Visual C# 2008 Express, allow for targeting .NET 3.5 (and easily transition to .NET 4.0), allow for WPF [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) to be created, [displayed as a well-behaved modal child dialog](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29178/753), and destroyed inside the ArcGIS Desktop applications, and provide logging, file open/save dialog, and message box services.

Looking for light-weight, minimal dependencies, promotes best design practices, etc. Everything else would be pretty much icing on the cake.

Or does everyone use Windows Forms still? :)

Comment: +1 Also please vote for [Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in ArcObjects](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bn56AAA) idea at Esri.

Comment: Pretty sure I have voted for that one at least twice now :)

Comment: Caliburn.Micro is great, it has all the features you need while being pretty lightweight. It is more suitable for scenarios where you have the whole WPF app under full control (as opposed to ArcGIS add-ins), which means you can take advantage of all its capabilities, including dependency injection etc a bit better. It also leans slightly towards viewmodel-first approach (while I prefer view-first), but I still believe there is no reason to look for other framework. That's my two cents anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback Petr. I have gone through a couple of Caliburn.Micro "Hello World" tutorials and successfully built a standalone WPF MVVM application with Caliburn.Micro 1.1 on .NET 3.5 with VC# 2008 Express using some pre-built binaries from [this page](http://www.firegarden.com/software/caliburn-micro-compile-net-3-5). That's like 3/4s of the battle. :) Hopefully I am not missing too much by using such an old version. Next step is working this into an ArcMap add-in. I presume I don't need to mess with the Bootstrapper since there is no "default" viewmodel in that scenario.

Comment: Never mind that, I ended up building from the latest source using the tips on the same page (used VS2010 on another machine, the built assembly works on VS2008 though).

Comment: Urk, .NET 3.5 seems to be hamstringing me here. I am trying to use the WindowManager as described on [this page](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/) but I do not have the `Export` attribute, which seems to only exist at .NET 4.0.

Comment: Oh that's an MEF thing. Guess I need to build a 3.5 version of that as well.

Comment: Grabbed the [MEF Preview 9](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/40606) which includes a 3.5 compatible build. Got ArcMap Add-In CM view resolution working by overriding SelectAssemblies in my bootstrapper and returning the add-in assembly. Apparently CM only looks in ArcMap.exe for your views by default.

Comment: I have used [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) in a WPF Runtime application and thought it added just enough to be useful without getting in the way with features. Good Blend support and the messaging framework would be the two features I liked best, but I have no experience with other frameworks.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing your experiences. I was looking at that one closely as well, seems very similar to Caliburn.Micro. So far I am pretty happy with CM although I did have to write a custom bootstrapper and window manager to work in the context of ArcGIS add-ins.

Comment: We are currently use PRISM, so far it has been a good option, the manage of events and communication across the modules is quite easy to manage